# Flurry iOS test Push Notification fails with UnrecognizedDeviceId

Tags: ios, push-notification, apple-push-notifications, flurry, flurry-analytics

Trying to integrate the Flurry Push Notification service on iOS.
When testing the integration I am getting

> Unable to send test push. Reason: UnrecognizedDeviceId. See troubleshooting documentation.

I am using the IDFA/IDFV

**Things I have already verified:**

- The Apple Push Sandbox SSL certificate is valid
- I am using correct FLurry API key
- User has granted all the notification permissions
- Looked at the [Test Push Troubleshooting](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/analytics/push/troubleshooting/), and `UnrecognizedDeviceId`. Nothing useful there!
- Make sure the IDFA/IDFV is correct

**I have done a complete setup following these guides:**

1. [Flurry Push for iOS](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/push/integration/ios/#flurry-push-for-ios)
2. [Push Authorization](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/push/authorization/)

The last step involves [Test Push](https://developer.yahoo.com/flurry/docs/push/testpush/send/#test-push).

Here is the code I'm using to registered Flurry in my app

```
#include "Flurry.h"
#include "FlurryMessaging.h"

:
:
:
- (BOOL) application:(UIApplication *)application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:(NSDictionary *)launchOptions
{
  [FlurryMessaging setAutoIntegrationForMessaging];
  [FlurryMessaging setMessagingDelegate:self];

  FlurrySessionBuilder* builder = [[FlurrySessionBuilder alloc] withIncludeBackgroundSessionsInMetrics:YES];
  [builder withLogLevel:FlurryLogLevelAll];
  [Flurry startSession:@"XXXXXX" withOptions:launchOptions withSessionBuilder:builder];
}

// To make sure iOS is registering notifications I added this override and it is being called with non-null deviceToken
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  NSString* tokenString = [deviceToken base64EncodedStringWithOptions:NSDataBase64EncodingEndLineWithLineFeed];

  NSLog(@"The generated device token string is : %@",tokenString);
}
```

Device Info:
iPhone7 Plus
iOS: 13.3.1

Any help appreciated!

#### ***Update 1***

Tried setting the `deviceToken` in Flurry but still the same error.

```
- (void)application:(UIApplication *)app didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken:(NSData *)deviceToken
{
  [FlurryMessaging setDeviceToken:deviceToken];
}
```

Comment: Hello! We are investigating this error, but we need some specific details. Can you email our support team at support@flurry.com with the API key of the app, and your phone's push token?

Comment: @FlurryAnalyticsSupport sure, sent out an email. Waiting for reply.

Comment: Did get a reply from the support team, they were able to fix the test notification issue _**on their end**_. Was able to test using the IDFA/IDFV tokens. Thanks @FlurryAnalyticsSupport